# Git Azure not able to clone repo in any way

Tags: git, azure, ssh

Recently I migrated my virtual machine from Parallels to VMWare fusion, but from there on I am not able to use git on Azure in any way (SSH/VS).
When I try to clone a repo from VS I get the following error:
[image]

and when I try to clone the repo with SSH I get the following:

```
Corrupted MAC on input. (770/4525)
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to *.*.*.* port 22: message authentication code incorrect
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I tried pretty much anything that I managed to find online (increased buffer size, ssh -m, etc. etc.), but nothing seems to work.
I am out of ideas and I really need help with that. Any suggestions on what should I do? 
Edit: same goes for push and pull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn out it was a VPN issue from host machine, had to install the VPN on guest OS also and now everything works as expected.