# git pull error: Message Authentication code incorrect

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I was able to git pull for quite some time. Now when I do, I am getting **Message Authentication code incorrect**.
Could not read from remote repository
Please make sure you have correct access rights and the repository exists

I have not made any configuration changes.
Please help me out with this issue.

Comment: Github or Bitbucket? HTTPS or SSH? Full text of the error message? Copy/paste from the terminal, please.

Comment: BitBucket. ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to (host) port 22: message authentication code incorrect. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and repository exists.

Comment: Most probably network problem; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68801884/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707203/7976758 It's not something we can fix here. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ssh_dispatch_run_fatal%3A+Connection+to+port+22%3A+message+authentication+code+incorrect

Comment: See also [ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: message authentication code incorrect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/328912/162084) for example. In general this means that the MAC data that ssh is using has been corrupted, either by bad hardware (typically a network device issue) or bad software (e.g., misconfigured VPN).